# mercurial: less duplication in hgrc file

Tags: mercurial

I have using Hg for some projects on my google code hosting. For each projects I set in [auth] section of .hgrc the username/password to push without every asking for password. But it is lots of duplication like:

```
[auth]
proj1.prefix = ... 111
proj1.username = google code username
proj1.password = google code password

proj2.prefix = ... 222
proj2.username = google code username
proj2.password = google code password
```

Can this somehow be doing with less duplications? Maybe set variable in hgrc and refer to it from all username/password lines?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from [auth](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#auth) section in hgrc:

> format: `<name>.<argument> = <value>` where `<name>` is used to group arguments into authentication entries.
>
> `<name>.prefix`: The authentication entry with the longest matching prefix is used

Hence, a single entry for code.google.com should suffice. Also of interest is `%include file` so you can store common things in seperate files and include them in any hgrc.

Answer (score 2):

[hgrc files](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html) don't seem to support variables as value for properties.

You can have multiple `.rc` files for your Mercurial config files thoug

> `*.rc` files from a single directory are read in alphabetical order, later ones overriding earlier ones

That means you could have:

- one main hgrc file
- one *template* file for project authentication
- one script able to generate multiple `proj.rc` files, one per project.

There is still duplication, but at least it is generated for you.

Comment: where are *rc placed? isn't it easier then simply have a script to generate my .hgrc from a template?

Comment: @zaharpopov: they are the "Per-installation/system configuration files" and are locate where you tell them to be (for Windows), or under `<install-root>/etc/mercurial/hgrc.d/*.rc` for Unix. You can off course generate only your own per-user `.hgrc` file, more appropriate for user informations.

Answer (score 1):

Just

```
[ui]
username = Ivan Pupkin <ivan.pupkin@gmail.com>
verbose = True

[auth]
googlecode.prefix = https://code.google.com/
googlecode.username = username
googlecode.password = password
```

I check it on hg 2.3.2 :)

Answer (score 0):

Different Google Code projects from the same user have not the same prefix, so you cannot use the prefix attribute in the auth section of hgrc.

But you can do it in a different way. Write a ~/.hgrc like this:

```
[auth]
gc.username = google code username
gc.password = google code password
```

And then for each project, make a PROJECTDIR/hgrc/.hgrc that looks like this:

```
[paths]
default = https://PROJECTNAME.googlecode.com/hg/

[auth]
gc.username = https://PROJECTNAME.googlecode.com/hg/
```

It is important that the name of the entry (gc in this case) is the same between the .hgrc and the project hgrc.